# Django not creating apps in the correct directory

Tags: python, django, frameworks, mongodb

I'm new to Django, so I may just not fully understand how it works yet.  I want to use Django with MongoDB, so I'm using [this library](https://github.com/vpulim/mango/) to connect the two.  So I created a new project, all went well.. then I ran the setup install script for "Mango", the MongoDB library that I added.

So now I'm at the point where I need to create a new "app" and the directory is being created in my /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mango-0.1-py2.6.egg/mysite/APP rather than /www/sites/mysite/APP, which is where all of my django files are..  Is that correct?  I have a funny feeling that the mango install script messed up my directory configuration somehow.  If that is indeed the wrong directory, how can I go about in fixing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your project directory, run: `python manage.py shell`

If you can then run the following from the interpreter, you should have everything installed correctly:

```
>>> from mango.auth import User
```

Comment: that works.. but is there any reason why my projects are being created under my /Library/Python directories and not where my site files is located?

Comment: I might have just had a funky bug during installation.  I deleted everything and started fresh and everything works perfectly now.